# RestKit Put service is not affecting database data on server even getting response is success

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am developing iPhone application and using Restkit for consuming services and put data on server. I am working with Restkit first time. I want to put data on server then I implemented the restkit put method, and it executed successfully and getting response "SUCCESS" but when I retrieving data then it doesn't affecting data means not getting last put data on server. So can anybody tell me what is wrong with this?? I used the following code I used :

```
////Response Mapping values
    RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableArray class]];
    [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"SenderId", @"SentDate", @"Status",@"GroupId", @"Message"]];

    //Request Mapping values
    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; // objectClass == NSMutableDictionary
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"SenderId", @"SentDate", @"Status",@"GroupId", @"Message"]];

    ITRestKitServices *restkitService = [[ITRestKitServices alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [restkitService putDataONserverBulletin:bulletinMutableArray pathPattern:@"bulletin" keyPath:@"" userName:appDelegate.user.Email password:appDelegate.user.SessionToken requestMapping:requestMapping responseMapping:responseMapping];
```

// And following code to put data on server in  service I used:

```
        // initialize AFNetworking HTTPClient
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL_STRING];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    [client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:userName password:password];

    //set pathPattern
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",BASE_PATH_STRING,pathPattern];

    //StatusCodes
    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

    //Request Descriptor
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor =
    [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                          objectClass:[Bulletin class]
                                          rootKeyPath:nil
                                               method:RKRequestMethodPUT];
    //Response Descriptor
    RKResponseDescriptor *userResponseDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodPUT
                                            pathPattern:path
                                                keyPath:keyPath
                                            statusCodes:statusCodes];


    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

    [objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:userResponseDescriptor];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(appDelegate.isLoading == NO)
    {
        [appDelegate startLoading];
    }

    [objectManager putObject:dataObject
                        path:path
                  parameters:nil
                     success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         NSLog(@"Bulletin Success");
     }
     failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         if(appDelegate.isLoading == YES)
         {
             [appDelegate stopLoading];
         }
         NSLog(@">>> Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

Comment: You have given zero details about your setup / code / debugging - so no. You need to gather details about what messages are passed between the client and server, what data is sent and any errors that are raised before anyone can help.

Comment: Thanks @Wain, see the code I posted here with question. I am always receiving Bulletin success but its not going change in database I don't why? I think its enough to for you.

Comment: Show the JSON. It's highly unlikely that the response descriptor should use `NSMutableArray`. Why aren't you using the response mapping result?

Comment: As we are putting data on server so not getting any data from server only getting response success or Error. No error is occurring and I tested it with NSObject class as response mapping too, but not working.

Comment: So I don't understand what you're expecting to happen that isn't working...

Comment: Actually I want to put data on server,sending nsmutable array of objects,it is not going to be insert into database.So how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should use Charles proxy to see what is sent and compare to what you want to be sent. Without knowing what the server expects you can't say what might be wrong with the mappings.

Comment: Thanks @Wain,Actually I tested it with Local server and at server side it is expected array of objects.So basically we are sending nsmutable array and its not going to be affected into database. It's working well for android.So can you suggest,how can we send objects array,by which server can accept it and get inserted in to database?

Comment: Show what ios sends, android sends and what `dataObject` is in your question.